# How do I generate a list of times by minute in KDB?

Tags: kdb

Let's say I have two datetimespans:

```
s: 2019.06.06D11:00:00.000000000
e: 2022.03.01D23:53:00.000000000
```

What would be the cleanest way to get a list of every inclusive minute between these two? (casting to `z` might be easier).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach would be faster that looping:

```
q)\ts a:s+0D00:01*til 1+"j"$(e-s)%0D00:01
17 33555136
q)\ts b:(e>)(+[00:01])\s
1640 48195648
q)a~b
1b
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue with a while.

```
(e>)(+[00:01])\s
```

If there is a better way, please let me know!